# How to express in a better way?

Tags: creative-writing, vocabulary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to overcome the fact that I can't write?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/563/how-to-overcome-the-fact-that-i-cant-write)

Normally I have good ideas to write, but when I come to writing those on paper it seems I don't have much vocabulary or good sentence making structure.

I know writing is a skill, but if some want to learn it, is it possible or is it an in-born quality? It takes lot of time to read a novel, so I don't like to read. But I want to write.

Can anybody suggest me the procedural way to be a good writer and the things I should take care of in day to day life to be a good writer?

Maybe my question is bogus, but I want to make sure from others that its bogus.

Comment: "It takes lot of time to read novel ...": True. And it takes even longer to learn to write well. So, start with **patience** and **perseverance**. Meanwhile, try some of the great short stories.

Comment: And no, your question is not bogus. Just be a good **reader** first and then start trying to be a good writer.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot be a writer if you don't write so the only way to learn how to write is write something. You can start by keeping a journal or a blog or both. You might be wondering what's the difference between the two and why I am suggesting both. Living in a technology-driven world, these two terms might be synonymous. But just to be clear, blog is an online journal/diary and the journal I'm referring to is the old fashioned way - pen and paper.

If you want to keep a blog, it would be better to join a community like http://www.deviantart.com/. People there are very nice and they provide excellent feedback on your posts (poetry, short story, articles etc).

I've read from an article from a writers' magazine some tips to improve your writing skills. The author suggested to keep a journal (pen and paper type) and write anything you want to write. For example, you're walking and you saw a house. You could practice writing by jotting down descriptive words about the house then afterwards pretend to describe it to someone by writing it down. Pretend that you are writing to a friend and you are describing to him/her about the beautiful house that you saw earlier. Or you could try to write a make-believe advertisement, pretending that you are a ad copy writer.

There are several ways to practice your writing. Reading is also a good way to learn how to write. You can learn new vocabulary words and writing styles by just reading. You can improve your craft by reading blogs of well-known writers or by subscribing to writer-related materials. **But still nothing beats practice. Write, write and write!**

Sorry for a lengthy post. Hope my suggestions help you to become a better writer you wanted to be. Cheers! :D